# How is the trigger pulse of the 555 timers generated?

Tags: clock, pulse, timing, trigger

I would like to connect an operational amplifier to the trigger circuit which then generates the pulse that starts the timing of the timer almost always connected to the clock generator.
Since 555 should consist of 23 transistors I think 2 capacitors if I remember well, I would like to understand, if I wanted to create a personal one, how the operational should be connected to the circuit of the trigger (trigger circuit is a part of 555 timer) because I'm not much interested to timing but the pulse signal that the trigger generates for timer, it is more on the impulse I would like to act on.

Comment: There are MANY block diagrams and descriptions of the internal workings of a 555 timer on web. Looking at some of these will allow you to easily answer your own questions. Having people provide another version of what is already so widely available is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

There are MANY block diagrams and descriptions of the internal workings of a 555 timer on web. Looking at some of these will allow you to easily answer your own questions. Having people provide another version of what is already so widely available is pointless.

You'll find a zillion diagrams with linked web pages [**here**](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=555+timer+operation&num=50&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPwKLauNTYAhUEjpAKHTqhBggQ_AUICigB&biw=1680&bih=870)

---

Operation of one mode explained with block diagram drawn in terms of standard circuit elements [**here**](https://circuitdigest.com/electronic-circuits/555-timer-astable-multivibrator-circuit-diagram)

Diagram from that page:

[image]

---

And another [**here**](http://www.electroschematics.com/4843/1-hz-pulse-generator/)

Related block diagram:

[image]